# Bottle cannot find route when separating "app" init, routes and main function into different files

Tags: bottle

routes.py:

```
from server import app


@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return "Hello World"
```

server.py:

```
from bottle import Bottle, run

app = Bottle()
#app.route("/index",method=["POST"])
```

run.py:

```
from server import app
from bottle import Bottle, run


if __name__ == "__main__":

    run(app, host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

After I split them into different files, I get the 404 error. I didn't find much information about this on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not importing `routes` anywhere, so `routes.py` is never executed.

If I were you, I would merge `routes.py` and `server.py`. But if you insist on separating them, then something like this might work:

run.py:

```
from bottle import Bottle, run
from server import app
import routes
...
```